# Type 'BlurView' does not conform to protocol 'UIViewRepresentable'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I keep getting this error on the first line. Code here:

```
struct BlurView : UIViewRepresentable {
    var style : UIBlurEffect.Style
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIVisualEffectView {
        let view = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: style))
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIVisualEffectView, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

Sorry if I'm missing something, I don't know much about UIViewRepresentable.

Comment: Remove the word "some" before `UIVisualEffectView`